# I get a C# SQL Connection error even though everything is correct

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been trying to connect my C# windows form to a SQL server and it always give me this error:

> Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Here is my code: (I replaced the username and password with "Test". I use remotemysql.com)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    connetionString = @"Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=test;Password=test";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You say SQL Server, but tag <mysql>. Which of them are you using?

Comment: @jarlh You're right. Seeing that remotemysql.com only offers MySQL hosting, OP seems to be confusing MySQL with SQL Server.

Comment: The connection string is syntacticly correct... but the server cannot be reached.

Comment: @jarlh oof i didnt know they are different ok now ik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is not found, because there is no sql server.

remotemysql.com is a mysql server.

In order to connect to a mysql server you have to install Oracle's MySql.Data NuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mysql.Data/). Then you can use the MySqlConnection instead of the SqlConnection class.

Comment: In which case the OP should also use a valid [MySQL connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You should add server as well into connetionString.
Smth like this(SQL server example):

"DbConnection": "Server=test.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=test_catalog;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
 If you connected to MySQL server, you should add correct connection for mySQL server and install correct nuget for mySQL for .net